# Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec (default-cli) on project mallet

Tags: maven, maven-plugin, mallet

When first running the example of [mallet](http://mallet.cs.umass.edu/download.php) project, I got following error.
My netbeans has Maven and also read the error instruction below. But I couldn't repair this problem. What should I do?

> Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec (default-cli) on project mallet: Command execution failed. Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1) -> [Help 1]
>
> To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
>   Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
>
> For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
>   [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException

**Pom file.**

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>cc.mallet</groupId>
  <artifactId>mallet</artifactId>
  <version>2.0.7-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <name>MAchine Learning for LanguagE Toolkit (MALLET)</name>
  <description>
    MALLET is a Java-based package for statistical natural language processing,
    document classification, clustering, topic modeling, information extraction,
    and other machine learning applications to text.
  </description>
  <url>http://mallet.cs.umass.edu/</url>
  <licenses>
    <license>
      <name>Common Public License Version 1.0</name>
      <url>http://www.eclipse.org/legal/cpl-v10.html</url>
      <distribution>repo</distribution>
    </license>
  </licenses>
  <scm>
    <url>http://hg-iesl.cs.umass.edu/hg/mallet</url>
  </scm>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <testSourceDirectory>src</testSourceDirectory>
  </build>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.8.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>bsh</groupId>
        <artifactId>bsh</artifactId>
        <version>2.0b4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jgrapht</groupId>
        <artifactId>jgrapht</artifactId>
        <version>0.6.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jwnl</groupId>
        <artifactId>jwnl</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>trove</groupId>
        <artifactId>trove</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mtj</groupId>
        <artifactId>mtj</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.9</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jdom</groupId>
        <artifactId>jdom</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <repositories>
    <!-- for JWNL -->
    <repository>
      <id>opennlp.sourceforge.net</id>
      <url>http://opennlp.sourceforge.net/maven2</url>
    </repository>
    <!-- for Trove -->
    <repository>
      <id>maven.ontotext.com</id>
      <url>http://maven.ontotext.com/archiva/repository/public</url>
    </repository>
    <!-- for MTJ -->
    <repository>
      <id>repo.scalanlp.org</id>
      <url>http://repo.scalanlp.org/repo</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
</project>
```

Comment: Have you tried it from plain command line (dos box)? Furthermore can you show the full pom file? And can you say what exactly is your problem?

Comment: I just want to run examples of mallet project. But when running examples, I got that error.

Comment: This just says that the command launched by the exec plugin returned "1", which is interpreted by the plugin as "command failed". So you should: know what command is launched (see the POM?) and inspect the output of that command to see why it fails. Without knowing more precisely what you do (what is "the first example of Mallet"?), community will not be able to help you much.